# Why do I get different dict object ids

Tags: python, multithreading

I have A django(version=1.1.4, python=2.7.15) application where I create A thread A to handle other tasks, and then thread A creates A process via subprocess.Popen.

data.py like this

```
class AttribDict(dict):
    """
    This class defines the appscan object, inheriting from Python data
    type dictionary.

    >>> foo = AttribDict()
    >>> foo.bar = 1
    >>> foo.bar
    1
    """

    def __init__(self, indict=None, attribute=None):
        if indict is None:
            indict = {}

        # Set any attributes here - before initialisation
        # these remain as normal attributes
        self.attribute = attribute
        dict.__init__(self, indict)
        self.__initialised = True

        # After initialisation, setting attributes
        # is the same as setting an item

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        """
        Maps values to attributes
        Only called if there *is NOT* an attribute with this name
        """

        try:
            return self.__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            raise AppscanDataException("unable to access item '%s'" % item)

    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        """
        Maps attributes to values
        Only if we are initialised
        """

        # This test allows attributes to be set in the __init__ method
        if "_AttribDict__initialised" not in self.__dict__:
            return dict.__setattr__(self, item, value)

        # Any normal attributes are handled normally
        elif item in self.__dict__:
            dict.__setattr__(self, item, value)

        else:
            self.__setitem__(item, value)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def __setstate__(self, dict):
        self.__dict__ = dict

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        retVal = self.__class__()
        memo[id(self)] = retVal

        for attr in dir(self):
            if not attr.startswith('_'):
                value = getattr(self, attr)
                if not isinstance(value,
                                  (types.BuiltinFunctionType,
                                   types.FunctionType, types.MethodType)):
                    setattr(retVal, attr, copy.deepcopy(value, memo))

        for key, value in self.items():
            retVal.__setitem__(key, copy.deepcopy(value, memo))

        return retVal

flu = AttribDict()
```

in manage.py like this:

```
from data import flu

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import thread
    from tasks import task
    thread.start_new_thread(task, ())
    with open('manage.txt','w') as w:
        w.write(str(flu) + '\n' + 'id:' + str(id(flu)))
    execute_manager(settings)
```

task.py like this:

```
def task():
    Popen('python start.py ', shell=True)
```

start.py like this:

```
def statrt():
    from config import init 
    from data import flu
    init()
    with open('C:start.txt','w') as w:
        w.write(str(flu) + '\n' + 'id:' + str(id(flu)))
```

init.py like this:

```
from data import flu

def init():
    flu.threads = 10
    res.threadpool = ThreadPool(flu.threads)
    with open('C:/init.txt','w') as w:
        w.write(str(flu) + '\n' + 'id:' + str(id(flu)))
```

Then I look at the three files `manage.txt` `start.txt` and `init.txt`

manage.txt like this:

```
{'threads': 10}
id: 191935728
```

start.txt like this:

```
{}
id: 195720888
```

init.txt like this:

```
{'threads': 10}
id: 191935728
```

May I ask why the ids of these three files are different? Why can't I get thread in start.txt?

Comment: It would help if you included the code where `flu` is defined.

Comment: Yes, I added code for flu

Comment: @D.T: In `def statrt():` the `import flu` are inside a function results in local namspace with new instance.